# layout file not showing recyclerView items in android

Tags: android, android-layout

This is my payout file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="com.wokoshop.sony.activity.ActivityShoppingCart">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_above="@+id/card_view"
        />

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="8dp"
            >

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/applyWallet"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Apply wallet"
                android:checked="true"
                android:layout_above="@+id/mainText"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/mainText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textColor="@color/primary_dark"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_above="@+id/placeOrderButton"
                />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/placeOrderButton"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="PLACE ORDER"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

It is displaying bottom card view items and toolbar. But not displaying recyclerView Items. items are available in recyclerView, But i am missing something in layout file (display part)

Can anyone help me what i am missing here?

Comment: is your recyclerview items getting displayed when you hide both toolbar and cardview?

Comment: @Jickson yes, if i hide cardView, recyclerView items are getting displayed.

Comment: ok. Where the cardview should be placed? is it at the bottom of the screen or end of recyclerview?

Comment: @Jickson, at bottom of screen. Both are same i think because there is no other elements between recyclerview and card view. But i want cardview to be visible always, that's why  i set android:layout_above="@+id/card_view" in recyclerview

Comment: Just set 'android:alignParentBottom="true"' to cardview. I have added this as answer. let me know if this works for you

Answer (score 0):

You have not set `layout_below` property in cardview. That is why your **recyclerview** is overlapped by **cardview**

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        tools:context="com.wokoshop.sony.activity.ActivityShoppingCart">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/card_view"
            android:alignParentBottom="true">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="8dp"
                >

                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/applyWallet"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Apply wallet"
                    android:checked="true"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/mainText"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/mainText"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/primary_dark"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/placeOrderButton"
                    />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/placeOrderButton"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="PLACE ORDER"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    />
            </RelativeLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_above="@+id/card_view"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This will create circular dependencies.. 'Exception raised during rendering: Circular dependencies cannot exist in RelativeLayout'

Comment: yes it will give and i tried also, giving error  Circular dependencies cannot exist in RelativeLayout.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But still same result. Showing only cardview, not recyclerview at all.

Comment: Is your screen having enough space to display both `recyclerview` and `cardview`? Can you attach the screenshot of current screen?

Comment: @HelloWorld I think this will be taken care by recyclerview scroll. I am just trying to have a card view in bottom of screen (always visible to user). Now recyclerview items will be displayed between toolbar and cardview.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="com.wokoshop.sony.activity.ActivityShoppingCart">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_above="@+id/card_view"
        />

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="8dp"
            >

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/applyWallet"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Apply wallet"
                android:checked="true"
                android:layout_above="@+id/mainText"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/mainText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textColor="@color/primary_dark"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_above="@+id/placeOrderButton"
                />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/placeOrderButton"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="PLACE ORDER"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Error:(26) No resource identifier found for attribute 'alignParentBottom' in package 'android' in cardview. i tried after replacing it with android:layout_alignParentBottom="true". After that same result Showing only cardview, not recyclerview at all

Comment: Sorry.. try 'android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"'

Answer (score 0):

try this i think it will solve your problem.....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context="com.wokoshop.sony.activity.ActivityShoppingCart">

<include
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    layout="@layout/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    />

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_below="@+id/recycler_view"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="8dp"
        >

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/applyWallet"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Apply wallet"
            android:checked="true"
            android:layout_above="@+id/mainText"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mainText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="@color/primary_dark"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_above="@+id/placeOrderButton"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/placeOrderButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="PLACE ORDER"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>
```